# What function outputs the biggest number for two given numbers taking care of both the sum and the difference of both?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, similitude

Let's say I have a tuple (a,b),

I want a fuction that combines:

```
f(a,b) grows with a+b
f(a,b) decreases with (a/b)
and
f(a,b) decreases with (b/a)
```

In other words I need a function that rewards not only the independent values of a and b but also their equality.

The reason for this is that I'm developing an adversarial evolutive algorithm of entities playing chess and I'm looking to minimize the explotation of any whites/blacks initial advantadge, or in other words I need to reward
those entities that win most matches independently of which side they play.

At the time I came with this:
By defining an absolute multiplicative value out of the sleave:

```
if 1 < x,
  @x@=x
and
if x < 1,
  @x@=1/x
and then:
if 0 < a + b,
    f(a,b)=(a+b)/|@a/b@|
and
if a+b < 0,
    f(a,b)=(a+b)+((a+b)/|@a/b@|)
```

My python fuction looks like this:

```
def mash(score):
    white=score[0]
    black=score[1]
    if (white==0) or (black==0):
      ratio=.1

    else:
        ratio=abs(white/black)
        if 1 < ratio:
           ratio=1/ratio

    if (white==0) and (black==0):
      ratio=0
    suma=black+white  
    if suma < 0:
        return (black+white)*(1+ratio)
    else:
        return (black+white)*ratio

mash([10,5])
```

Comment: I've read your post several times now, and I still cannot figure what you are after. What do you mean by "taking care of" in the title? You mention the difference in the title, but talk about the ratio in the question. If you increase $a$ even by a small amount, but not $b$, then both $a+b$ and $a/b$ increase. You cannot have a function increase with one but decrease with the other. What is "reward the independent values of $a$ and $b$ but also their equality" supposed to mean? What is an "absolute multiplicative value out of the sleave"? What is $@x@$? What do you want here?

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is something like (a+b)*e^-|a/b| (e^-|x|=absolute multiplicative of x). It's all explained in the body, im looking for a type of average that doesn't increase if 'a' is too much higher than 'b' and viceversa, since I'm not only looking for the player that wins more matches, but also the one that wins more equally weather it plays black or white. E.g. A player could be winning most matches but because he always wins with blacks, and I want to exclude that player. @PaulSinclair